# Exclude files in classpath during Gradle build?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am using Gradle to build an Eclipse project. In the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` directories, there are `package-info.java` files. Eclipse will complain that the **type package-info is already defined** when I import the project. Within Eclipse, I excluded these files that are in the `src/test/java` directory, so my `.classpath` file contains the following line:

`<classpathentry excluding="**/package-info.java" kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>`

How do I configure Gradle so that it builds an Eclipse project and excludes the `package-info.java` files that are in the `src/test/java` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to my `build.gradle` file, and it worked for me.

```
sourceSets.test.resources {
    srcDirs = ["src/test/java"]
    exclude "**/package-info.java"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding the following piece of code should do the job:

```
compileJava {
    excludes = ['**/package-info.java']
}
```

Removing all the mentioned files will also work ;)

Comment: This took me forever to find the solution to, thanks for posting!

Lots of other solutions online involve `sourceSets` and that did not work for me